# Обработка классов, повторяющийся код

Tags: java, android, realm

У меня есть несколько классов данных (например, realm таблицы). Я обрабатываю каждый из них одинкаовым способом (см. код ниже).

Меняются только имена классов : "Ticket.class", далее например "SecondTable.class" и т.д. Имена классов заранее известны.

Q1. Как мне определить метод с аргументом типа класс ?

Q2. Или как сделать что-то типа "for each [classes] do ..." ?

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmResults<Ticket> tickets = realm.where(Ticket.class)
            .findAll();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = tickets.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        if ... {
            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)...;
            StartMyAsyncTask().execute(tickets.get(i));
            // etc...

            // delete from DB
            tickets.get(i).removeFromRealm();
        }
    }
    realm.commitTransaction();



   public class Ticket extends RealmObject {... }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дублирую свой [ответ со StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43972361/3926506)

Можно создать некий *объединяющий* интерфейс:

```
public interface IAction {
    void action(); 
}
```

для классов`Ticket` и `SecondTable`, а затем реализовать его в соответствии с логикой класса:

```
public class Ticket extends RealmObject implements IAction {

    @Override
    public void action(){...}
}
```

Следующим шагом нужно создать *шаблонный метод* (полагаю, определить его можно в классе утилит):

```
public static <T extends RealmObject & IAction> void yorForEachMethod(Class<T> cls) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmResults realmObjects = realm.where(cls).findAll();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = realmObjects.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ... {
            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)...;
            // здесь можно безопасно приводить к типу интерфейса IAction и вызывать его методы
            ((IAction)realmObjects.get(i)).action();
            // или можно передавать интерфейс в асинхронную задачу
            //StartMyAsyncTask().execute((IAction)realmObjects.get(i));
            // etc...

            // delete from DB
            realmObjects.get(i).removeFromRealm();
        }
    }
    realm.commitTransaction(); 
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! То что надо.

Comment: @tim4dev, рад помочь ) Если это решило твою проблему, нужно принять ответ https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: И на [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43961355/class-processing-recurring-code/43972361#43972361), я вижу и там ты отметился )